# accessing a blade when not authenticated shows as error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The posts page can be accessed by non-members, so I'm trying to make it accessible, but I'm having the following error :

```
Call to a member function postusers() on a non-object
```

This error doesn't show if I typed the URL while authenticated.

postusers() method in Users model :

```
public function postusers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Postusr');
    }
```

blade usage of postusers():

```
@if( Auth::user()->postusers()->where('post_id', $post->id)->where('follow', 1)->exists())
```

I simply want to access this page if I'm not autheticated.

Comment: you will need to check if there is an authenticated user before trying to use it ... we have `@auth` and `@guest` blade conditional helpers if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if there is an authenticated user before trying to make calls to an object that might not exist:

```
@if (Auth::check())
    ... user is authenticated
@endif

@if (Auth::user())
    ... user is authenticated
@endif
```

[Laravel 5.2 Docs - Authentication - Retrieving the Authenticated User](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Auth::user()` method returns the autenticated user, or null if there is none. So the error is happening because you are calling `postusers()` on null.

To fix this, you should first test if the user is authenticated, then try to call the method:

1. Use the @auth directive, so this code will only execute if the user is authenticated:

```
@auth
  @if(...)
@endauth
```

2. Test if there is an user before calling the method:

`@if(Auth::user() && ...)`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by blade directive @auth

```
@auth
@if( Auth::user()->postusers()->where('post_id', $post->id)->where('follow', 1)->exists())
@endauth
```

Comment: which version do you use?